# bash: No space left on device

Tags: ubuntu, storage, virtualbox

There are quite a few similar questions to this. However, all of them show that there are some file systems that are indeed out of space. My case seems to slightly be different:

```
randolph@virus:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           799M  876K  798M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        28G   14G   12G  54% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G   76K  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   32K  100M   1% /run/user

randolph@virus:~$ df -ih
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             996K   443  996K    1% /dev
tmpfs            999K   403  998K    1% /run
/dev/sda1        1.8M  1.8M     1  100% /
none             999K     2  999K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             999K     3  999K    1% /run/lock
none             999K     4  999K    1% /run/shm
none             999K    24  999K    1% /run/user
```

I don't know what it means when it says the inode used is 100%.

Could this be the cause of the issue? How can I resolve this?

Background: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on virtualbox.

Comment: you can use du -sh on root/home directory to know the exact culprit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many files on the filesystem so you've run out of inodes. Even though there would be space to write more data, if there are no inodes available you can't create new files.

You have to find why you have extra files. They may be some zero byte pesks that just take inodes but no data space.